# PHP. Create value for unchecked box in the array

Tags: php

I have following table:

```
<form action="update-table.php" method="post">
<table class="table-data" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Live</td>
            <td>User</td>
            <td>Last Update</td>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="id[]" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="1" /></td>
            <td><input name="live[]" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1"/></td>
            <td>admin@website.com</td>
            <td>August 18, 2011, 10:10 am</td>
            <td>Title1</td>
            <td>Content1</td>
            <td><a href="edit-news.php?editID=1">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="delete-news.php?deleteID=1">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="id[]" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="2" /></td>
            <td><input name="live[]" type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>admin@website.com</td>
            <td>August 18, 2011, 10:11 am</td>
            <td>Title2</td>
            <td>Content2</td>
            <td><a href="edit-news.php?editID=2">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="delete-news.php?deleteID=2">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="id[]" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="3" /></td>
            <td><input name="live[]" type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>admin@website.com</td>
            <td>August 18, 2011, 10:10 am</td>
            <td>Title3</td>
            <td>Content3</td>
            <td><a href="edit-news.php?editID=3">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="delete-news.php?deleteID=3">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" />
```

**What I'm trying to do is  display the array send with `$_POST`.**

**The problem is when checkbox is not checked - nothing is being send.**

**How to check if the `$_POST['live']` is set, and if not - set it's value to 0?**

The following code does not work. Why?

```
if (!isset($_POST['live'])) {
            $_POST['live'] = "0";
        }


        for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['id']);$i++) {

          echo "<p>".$_POST['id'][$i]."</p>";
          echo "<p>".$_POST['live'][$i]."</p>";
          echo "<hr />";

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['id']);$i++) {

    if(!isset($_POST['live'][$i])){
        $_POST['live'][$i] = "0";
    }

    echo "<p>".$_POST['id'][$i]."</p>";
    echo "<p>".$_POST['live'][$i]."</p>";
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

Comment: Well, before the loop you are essentially checking if the array of live is set, so if one live variable is set you'll be evaluating it as true, otherwise, you'll be changing `$_POST['live']` from an array to an int. Also, you'll get a wraning if you try and echo `$_POST['live'][$i]` as there is no such value - so its best to wrap it in an if/else statement before trying to echo it.

Comment: ok, but this way would not be possible if I would be doing SQL update query. Which is my goal. Is there any way to check values of `live`(and change it if no set) but keep it as an array?

Comment: do we need that if/else statement any more in `echo` if it is on the top as well?

Comment: Oh yes, you can take that out and replace it back with the original. see my edit.